# How to properly resume enumerate independent of depth?

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate, enumitem

I would like to have enumerate resume independent of the depth. I can't manage to get it working with setlist's `resume` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{resume}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\end{enumerate}

\begin{proof}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Two
\end{enumerate}

\end{proof}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The solution seems to be the usage of the newer option `resume*`. However, I am wondering why there is no `resume*` option for the list. Instead, I need to add the `resume*` option to the enumerate environments. The next thing, I am wondering is why the `resume` option added to **each** of the environments works (while giving the unintended numbering) but it does not work with `resume*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item One
\end{enumerate}

\begin{proof}

\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item Two
\end{enumerate}

\end{proof}

\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item Three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It works as expected when adding the `resume*` option to each of the enumerate environments **except** for the first one. I find the difference between how `resume` and `resume*` works a bit of a head scratcher. Maybe I am just misunderstanding how to work with the resume options properly?

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for the feedback. That is strange. MiKTeX does not report any updates and enumitem is at 3.9 which seems also to be the latest.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'd be interested what your output is. Is it 1, 2, 3 or 1, 2, 2?

Comment: @AlanMunn Okay, I missed to add the `resume*` option to the first environment. Do you get my second output now? I am still surprised that the first snippet gives you 1, 2, 3 rather than 1, 2, 2...

Comment: I've deleted my comment. I misread the second output. For the first code I get 1.2.2, and the second 1.2.3.

Comment: But a couple of other comments: the `resume*` has nothing to do with this, as `resume` in your second code example works as you would expect. `resume*` can't be used in `\setlist` because by definition it copies all the settings from the list, so it doesn't make sense to use it in `\setlist`. So I think that your first example is bug.  You can report it here: https://www.texnia.com/contact.html